# How to tackle the Massachusetts roads dataset using CNN in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

![sample training input]http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/data/mass_roads/train/sat/10078660_15.tiff

![sample training output]
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/data/mass_roads/train/map/10078660_15.tif

I am a beginner to CNN , and have  worked with the MNIST dataset  in which we input 28x28x3 images and output a 10x1 vector containing probabilities of the 10 classes(0,1,2,3---,9). 
How do we extract only the road pixels from the input image and display them, as is represented by the output image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problems is a binary segmentation problem. In a sense you learn a mapping from satellite images and predict for each pixel, iff this pixel is part of the road. A simple algorithm to do this would be to check if the pixel color is part of some range.

A CNN naturally will learn you a more complicated function based on the local neighborhood of said pixel. One repo to get you started should be this one: https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation. Therein they use a similar algorithm to segment ultrasound images using CNNs. You just have to use 3 input channels instead of 1 and everything else should be quite similar.

Comment: The dimensions of each satellite image is (1500,1500,3)[Here,3 = no. of channels].Therefore it is causing a memory error. How do I deal with that?

Comment: I would advise on 1 of three approaches. Either use Large initial filters with large strides( e.g 7x7 filters with 4x4 stride), downsample the image first and then run the algorithm or run the algorithm on distinct parts and then stich the images together.